# One signal received by multiple threads

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads, signals, posix

I am trying to write a program that will create 10 threads. Those threads after receiving SIGUSR1 signal should all stop, and after receiving SIGUSR2 should continue doing what they were doing.

I've written this piece of code( btw. Can you also please check it for correctness ? Thank You! ) but I think that when signal SIGUSR1 occurs only 1 thread will receive and handle it (which means only 1 thread will continue its work...).

How do I make all the threads that are waiting continue their work?

```
void handle_sigusr1()
{
    int sig;
    sigset_t set;
    sigemptyset(&set);
    sigaddset(&set, SIGUSR2);
    printf("Thread waiting for some signal SIGUSR2! \n");
    sigwait(&set, &sig);
}

void install_sigusr1()
{
  struct sigaction setup_action;
  sigset_t block_mask;

  sigfillset(&block_mask);
  setup_action.sa_handler = handle_sigusr1;
  setup_action.sa_mask = block_mask;
  setup_action.sa_flags = 0;
  if (sigaction (SIGUSR1, &setup_action, 0) == -1)
    fprintf(stderr, "sigaction2 err");
}

void* test_thread_func(void * data)
{
    while(1)
    {
        ...
        Some SIGUSR1 signal may occur ...
        ...
    }
}

void create_threads()
{
    pthread_t TH[10];
    int i;
    sigset_t set;
    sigfillset(&set);
    sigdelset(&set, SIGUSR1);
    sigdelset(&set, SIGUSR2);
    pthread_sigmask(SIG_SETMASK, &set, NULL);
    install_sigusr1();
    /* Block all signals except for SIGUSR1 and SIGUSR2. New Threads will
         inherit the sigmask ...*/
    pthread_attr_t attr;
    pthread_attr_init(&attr);
    for(i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        pthread_create(TH[i], &attr, test_thread_func, 0);
    }
    // now we unblock SIGINT so that the main thread only can handle SIGINT signal
    sigdelset(&set, SIGINT);
    // we dont want the main thread to handle SIGUSRs signals ...
    sigaddset(&set, SIGUSR1);
    sigaddset(&set, SIGUSR2);
    pthread_sigmask(SIG_SETMASK, &set, NULL);
    while(1);
}
```

Comment: this seems to be a run time problem, but there is no example inputs, desired outputs, actual outputs AND the posted code does not cleanly compile.  (missing main(), #includes, etc) Please post code that cleanly compiles, please post the inputs, please post the actual outputs please post the desired outputs

Comment: Since only a single thread receives a given signal, signals are probably not the appropriate mechanism to control the operations. I suspect that you could use `pthread_cond_broadcast()` to wake up all the threads, which means they need to be waiting on the condition. The thread that reacts to SIGUSR2 would need to call that (but note that none of the `pthread_*` functions are safe for use in a signal handler). I'm not immediately sure how you'd go about making all the threads go and wait on the condition when SIGUSR1 is received. I don't know of a way to send a signal to a specific thread.

Comment: You can't safely call `printf()` in a signal handler.  `printf()` is not async-signal-safe.

Comment: Is this homework you [share with another user](http://stackoverflow.com/q/34386514/132382)?

Answer (score 1):

> How do I make all the threads that are waiting continue their work?

The [pthread_cond_broadcast()](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/pthread_cond_broadcast.html) function shall unblock all threads currently blocked on the specified condition variable cond.

> I've written this piece of code( btw. Can you also please check it for
>   correctness ?)

For this post your complete code.  This is something what I can tell you from your questions.