# pthread - Pausing/Unpausing all threads

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads, conditional-statements

I'm trying to write a pause/unpause all threads in my application, which is activated by SIGUSR1 (pause) and SIGUSR2 (unpause). I thought of using `pthread_cond_wait()` in all threads and, when signal is received, use `pthread_cond_broadcast()` on conditional I would hang all threads on, but apparently it is not safe to use `pthread_cond_broadcast()` in signal handler... Is there any alternate solution to this problem (I must avoid busy wait)?

Comment: I can't pause thread in every place, e.g. if they are waiting on message queue for the message from other process, they should finish doing that before pausing.

Comment: How is your processing loop set up? If it is `select` based then the `select` will return an error with `errno` set to `EINTR` when it is interrupted by any signal. At that point you can send the broadcast. Or you can even explicitly incorporate the signal into your processing loop with `signalfd`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may use dedicated thread for wait signals using [sigwait](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/sigwait.3.html). When signal is received, waiting is returned, and given thread may inform other threads within *normal code* (not a signal handler).

Assuming you have functions for pause and unpause threads like these

```
int paused;
pthread_mutex m;
pthread_cond cond;

void pause_threads(void)
{
    pthread_mutex_lock(&m);
    paused = 1;
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&m);        
}

void unpause_threads(void)
{
    pthread_mutex_lock(&m);
    paused = 0;
    pthread_cond_broadcast(&cond);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&m);        
}
```

dedicated thread can be implemented in this way:

```
// Block signals for wait
sigset_t usr_set;

sigemptyset(&usr_set);
sigaddset(&usr_set, SIGUSR1);
sigaddset(&usr_set, SIGUSR2);
pthread_sigmask(SIG_BLOCK, &usr_set, NULL);

// If other threads will be created from given one, they will share signal handling.
// Otherwise actions above should be repeated for new threads.

int sig;
// Repeatedly wait for signals arriving.
while(!sigwait(&usr_set, &sig)) {
    if(sig == SIGUSR1) {
        pause_threads();
    }
    else {
        unpause_threads();
    }
}
```

Comment: This is the right direction.  Three remarks.  First, it is not necessary to change the signals' disposition to SIG_IGN, since `sigwait` _accepts_ a pending signal without _delivering_ it.  Second, we know the code is multithreaded and thus must use `pthread_sigmask` and not `sigprocmask` (undefined behavior in multithreaded code).  Third, this answer is incomplete — it needs to be married to something like [@Martinn's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34386678/132382) to be a complete solution.

Comment: @pilcrow: Thanks for remarks! Before I thought that any catched signal should be processed (when not blocked). Now I see that `sigwait` is exception from that rule. As for 3rd remark, according to the question post OP definitely knows what to do with catched signals. But I have added some example code for illustrativness purposes.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried something like this:

```
pthread_mutex_lock(&m_suspend_mutex);
  while (m_suspend_flag == 1)
    {
      pthread_cond_wait(&m_resume_cond, &m_suspend_mutex);
    }
  pthread_mutex_unlock(&m_suspend_mutex);
```

This will pause the thread until another thread sets `m_suspend_flag` to 0. This can be placed in a strategic location in your thread execution cycle. For your scenario you can place this bit of code after your thread checks if there are any messages in a message queue.

Comment: The problem is, I need to hang ALL threads, so if I do that on every thread, there is no thread left to wake them up...

Comment: What's going to resume the last thread that you pause though?

Comment: I want to unpause all threads on receiving SIGUSR2, that's exactly the problem I'm trying to solve. Small addition - I don't need to hang all threads, if there is a way to write some thread that would wake all the others up on reveiving SIGUSR2, WITHOUT busy wait, that would also be the valid solution.

Comment: The while loops makes it look like a busy wait, but the thread will actually block at pthread_cond_wait() until it's resumed, so it won't waste any CPU cycles. See: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908775/xsh/pthread_cond_wait.html